# How to compare 2 users input on radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

Can anyone offer guidance on methods for ranking the similarity of sets?

I have 2 users answering questions by ticking 3 radio buttons of yes, no and maybe.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm for comparing, individually and as a set, the similarity of respondents' answers to each question? I have to implement this on a PHP/MySQL platform.

Thanks

Comment: Plz define `similarity`.

Comment: why don't you just set a integer value for all three of your radio button, so if you have to compare, you can compare base on the integer value;

Comment: what is the definition for "degree to similarity" for u on 3 inputs only???

Comment: The root of this question seems to rest in Math, however the question is too ambiguous to migrate to a sister site. If you can edit this for clarity, flag it for moderator review.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a math question. She asks how to approach the problem, which is a question of algorithm and therefore entirely appropriate to this site.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to compute strength of correlation.

For each response pair, compute a degree of similarity by measuring the distance between the two answers. Treat No, Maybe, Yes as 0, 1, 2 (or 1,2,3 if that suits PHP better) and simply subtract response A from response B.

Thus, for respondents A and B we compute distance *d*:

```
A  B                d
0  0   Abs(0 - 0) = 0
0  1   Abs(1 - 0) = 1
0  2   Abs(2 - 0) = 2

1  0   Abs(0 - 1) = 1
1  1   Abs(1 - 1) = 0
1  2   Abs(2 - 1) = 1

2  0   Abs(0 - 2) = 2
2  1   Abs(1 - 2) = 1
2  2   Abs(2 - 2) = 0
```

This gives you a similarity score for the question. Now all you need to do to determine similarity of the responses to a group of questions is add the scores and express this as a fraction of the maximum possible score. MaxScore is simply the maximum distance multiplied by the number of questions (eg for 100 questions the maximum score is 200)

If you had a range of five possible answers per question the max score for 100 questions would be 400.